# How to classify an ordered ascending {0, 5, 5, 10, 19, 22, 23} into several classes {{0,9},{10,19}, ...}?

Tags: list-manipulation

I attempted to classify an increasingly ordered list into several classes to make frequency distribution table. I am faced with a difficulty to nest two pure functions: one for  `TakeWhile` second argument and the other one for mapping with `/@`. To which pure function does the `#` belong? It is confusing!

```
TakeWhile[data, #[[1]] <= # <= #[[2]]] & /@ class
```

Then I attempted to use `Function` to mitigate the ambiguity  as follows.

```
TakeWhile[data, Function[u, #[[1]] <= u <= #[[2]]]] & /@ class
```

Unfortunately it produces unexpected result as follows.

```
ClearAll[data, class]
data = RandomInteger[100, 20] // Sort
class = Table[{10 i, 10 i + 9}, {i, 0, 9}]
TakeWhile[data, Function[u, #[[1]] <= u <= #[[2]]]] & /@ class
```

outputs

```
{0, 5, 5, 10, 19, 22, 23, 24, 25, 33, 34, 40, 40, 42, 53, 62, 69, 74, 91, 91}

{{0, 9}, {10, 19}, {20, 29}, {30, 39}, {40, 49}, {50, 59}, {60,  69}, {70, 79}, {80, 89}, {90, 99}}

{{0, 5, 5}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}}
```

## Edit

In order to make the existing answers usable to my real scenario, let me explain a bit about the `class` interval. The class given above is just a simplification of my real scenario.

Consider the following code. `l` is a list of the lower bound of each class interval.

```
ClearAll[data, n, r, k, w]
data = {
    26, 22, 44, 60, 55, 58, 45, 42, 41, 44, 39, 55, 57, 52, 59, 46, 
    54, 56, 22, 58, 54, 34, 69, 33, 61, 20, 62, 29, 24, 53, 51, 23, 
    20, 38, 34, 52, 36, 52, 52, 43, 30, 51, 49, 45, 39, 42, 32, 29, 
    34, 47, 34, 35, 21, 54, 52, 51, 38, 57, 58, 53, 55, 44, 27, 29, 
    52, 22, 34, 56, 45, 53, 18, 46, 53, 51, 63, 57, 56, 28, 22, 17, 
    49, 21, 58, 61, 51, 28, 35, 42, 24, 55, 19, 34, 62, 30, 35, 32, 
    57, 47, 20, 36
    } // Sort;
n = Length@data;
r = Last@data - First@data;
k = 1 + 3.322 Log[10, n] // Ceiling;
w = r/k // Ceiling;
l = Table[First@data + w*i , {i, 0, k - 1}]
```

Comment: `BinLists` (shown by kglr) works for you new example: `BinLists[data, {l}]`.

Comment: @C.E.: Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
data = {0, 5, 5, 10, 19, 22, 23, 24, 25, 33, 34, 40, 40, 42, 53, 62, 69, 74, 91, 91};
```

#### GatherBy

```
GatherBy[data, Quotient[#, 10] &]
```

> ```
> {{0, 5, 5}, {10, 19}, {22, 23, 24, 25}, {33, 34}, {40, 40, 42}, {53},
> {62, 69}, {74}, {91, 91}}
> ```

#### Split

```
Split[data, SameQ @@ Quotient[{##}, 10] &]
```

> ```
> {{0, 5, 5}, {10, 19}, {22, 23, 24, 25}, {33, 34}, {40, 40, 42}, {53},
> {62, 69}, {74}, {91, 91}}
> ```

#### GroupBy

```
Values @ GroupBy[Quotient[#, 10] &] @ data
```

> ```
> {{0, 5, 5}, {10, 19}, {22, 23, 24, 25}, {33, 34}, {40, 40, 42}, {53},
> {62, 69}, {74}, {91, 91}}
> ```

#### BinLists

```
DeleteCases[{}] @ BinLists[data, 10]
```

> ```
> {{0, 5, 5}, {10, 19}, {22, 23, 24, 25}, {33, 34}, {40, 40, 42}, {53},
> {62, 69}, {74}, {91, 91}}
> ```

Or use the second column of you `class` as bin limits:

```
binlims = {Join[{-Infinity}, class[[All, 2]], {Infinity}]};
DeleteCases[{}] @ BinLists[data, binlims]
```

> ```
> {{0, 5, 5}, {10, 19}, {22, 23, 24, 25}, {33, 34}, {40, 40, 42}, {53},
> {62, 69}, {74}, {91, 91}}
> ```

Answer (score 6):

- A *slot* `#` always binds itself to the nearest `&` outside. In your first attempt:

  ```
  TakeWhile[data, #[[1]] <= # <= #[[2]]] & /@ class
  ```

  the three slots in `#[[1]] <= # <= #[[2]]` simply belong to the only `&` and are thus mapped to `class`.
- What is desired? We want that `#[[1]]` and `#[[2]]` belong to the function used on `class`, and that the middle `#` belongs to the 2nd argument of `TakeWhile`. One may hence suggest

  ```
  TakeWhile[data, #[[1]] <= #1 <= #[[2]] &] & /@ class
  ```

  This seems right. But don't forget `#` is equivalent to `#1`. They all bind themselves to the nearest `&`, which is the argument of `TakeWhile`.
- So the solution (for the `#`-`&` problem) is as the second attempt of OP:

  ```
  TakeWhile[data, Function[u, #[[1]] <= u <= #[[2]]]] & /@ class
  ```

  but it still doesn't work. Now the problem is the logic. We know that `TakeWhile` scans from the first element of the list. By this, we're giving every `class` the **same** list, `data`. As a result, *e.g.*, for`{10, 19}` in `class`, since the first element `0` of `data` is not within this range, it immediately halts and returns `{}`, as can be seen in the output.
- As a solution, we should take elements (that we want) out, and drop[pass] the rest (that we don't yet need) to the next list of `class`. This can be done by `TakeDrop`, and the whole iteration can be done by `FoldPairList`:

  ```
  FoldPairList[
  TakeDrop[
     #1, LengthWhile[#1, u \[Function] Between[u, #2]]
                  (*     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                     or `Between[#2]                 `, the operator form, shorter *)
     ] &, data, class]
  ```

  > ```
  > {{0, 5, 5}, {10, 19}, {22, 23, 24, 25}, {33, 34}, {40, 40, 
  >   42}, {53}, {62, 69}, {74}, {}, {91, 91}}
  > ```
- Of course, often the wheel has been invented:

  ```
  BinLists[data, {Table[10 i, {i, 0, 10}]}]
  ```

  > ```
  > {{0, 5, 5}, {10, 19}, {22, 23, 24, 25}, {33, 34}, {40, 40, 
  >   42}, {53}, {62, 69}, {74}, {}, {91, 91}}
  > ```

## For *Edit*

We can get `class`es from lower bounds `l`:

```
class = Partition[Flatten@{l, Infinity}, 2, 1]
```

> ```
> {{17, 24}, {24, 31}, {31, 38}, {38, 45}, {45, 52}, {52, 59}, {59, 
>   66}, {66, \[Infinity]}}
> ```

and use the `TakeWhile` method. Or, simply

```
BinLists[data, {Flatten@{l, Infinity}}]
```

> ```
> {{17, 18, 19, 20, 20, 20, 21, 21, 22, 22, 22, 22, 23}, {24, 24, 26, 
>   27, 28, 28, 29, 29, 29, 30, 30}, {32, 32, 33, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 
>   34, 35, 35, 35, 36, 36}, {38, 38, 39, 39, 41, 42, 42, 42, 43, 44, 
>   44, 44}, {45, 45, 45, 46, 46, 47, 47, 49, 49, 51, 51, 51, 51, 
>   51}, {52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 53, 53, 53, 53, 54, 54, 54, 55, 55, 
>   55, 55, 56, 56, 56, 57, 57, 57, 57, 58, 58, 58, 58}, {59, 60, 61, 
>   61, 62, 62, 63}, {69}}
> ```

Answer (score 4):

Just a quick benchmark of kglr's methods in version 10.1.

```
f1[data_] := GatherBy[data, Quotient[#, 10] &];
f2[data_] := Split[data, SameQ @@ Quotient[{##}, 10] &];
f3[data_] := Values@GroupBy[Quotient[#, 10] &]@data;
f4[data_] := DeleteCases[{}]@BinLists[data, 10];
f5[data_] := SplitBy[data, Quotient[#, 10] &];

Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]

BenchmarkPlot[{f1, f2, f3, f4, f5}, Sort@RandomInteger[5 #, #] &, 
 "IncludeFits" -> True]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
data = 
 {0, 5, 5, 10, 19, 22, 23, 24, 25, 33, 34, 40, 40, 42, 53, 62, 69, 74, 91, 91};
```

Two more possibilities

```
GatherBy[data, Floor[# / 10] &]
```

{{0, 5, 5}, {10, 19}, {22, 23, 24, 25}, {33, 34}, {40, 40,
42}, {53}, {62, 69}, {74}, {91, 91}}

```
Internal`CopyListStructure[Split @ IntegerPart[data / 10], data]
```

{{0, 5, 5}, {10, 19}, {22, 23, 24, 25}, {33, 34}, {40, 40,
42}, {53}, {62, 69}, {74}, {91, 91}}

Answer (score 1):

```
data = {0, 5, 5, 10, 19, 22, 23, 24, 25, 33, 34, 40, 40, 42, 53, 62, 69, 74, 91, 91};
```

---

An alternative is to use `Cases`:

```
f = Cases[data, x_ /; Or @@ Thread[Quotient[x, 10] == #]] &;

f /@ Union[Quotient[#, 10] & /@ data]
```

*Result*:

> {{0, 5, 5}, {10, 19}, {22, 23, 24, 25}, {33, 34}, {40, 40,
> 42}, {53}, {62, 69}, {74}, {91, 91}}

Answer (score 0):

```
data = {0, 5, 5, 10, 19, 22, 23, 24, 25, 33, 34, 40, 40, 42, 53, 62, 
   69, 74, 91, 91};

SecondLast = #[[-2]] &;

GatherBy[data, SecondLast@IntegerDigits[#, 10, BitLength@Max@data] &]
```

---

> {{0, 5, 5}, {10, 19}, {22, 23, 24, 25}, {33, 34}, {40, 40,    42},
> {53}, {62, 69}, {74}, {91, 91}}